# On Redux-Form, can I process values after validation, but before they are submitted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using [Redux-Form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) and I have the following scenario:

Numbers and date-times are peculiar because they may be **invalid** until you finished filling out the fields (e.g `12/08/`). Also, you may have multiple strings representing the same value (e.g `2.5000` and `2.5`).

For that reason, I decided to keep all fields as **strings** both on the forms and in the application state.

The problem is that I need, after validation, to process the values of the fields so that the JSON going to the server actually have numbers and date-times and not just strings.

Is this the ideal solution? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning seems sound. You've already got a "formatter" running to convert your data into strings, so you just need its compliment, a "parser", between the form `onSubmit` and the ajax call.

```
render() {
  const { fields, handleSubmit } = this.props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(values => {
        // all values are guaranteed to pass sync validation here,
        // so they should all parse just fine.
        const parsedValues = parseIntoRealDataTypes(values)
        return ajax.post('/api/myWidgets', parsedValues)
          .then(response => {
            // rejoice
          })
      })}>
    </form>
  )
}
```